# specifically add javascript to class but not to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, document-ready

How would you specifically add some javascript to one class, but definitely not to another class.

My simple javascript is below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('.slider').foggy();
  });
</script>
```

I want to apply the 'foggy()' to the class **.slide**

But I definitely don't want to apply it to apply it to the class **.slide.swiper-slide-visible.swiper-slide-active**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this with `:not(selector)`

```
$('.slider:not(selectorClassToExclude)').foggy();
```

Like you don't want to add foggy() to **.slide.swiper-slide-visible.swiper-slide-active** code would be:

```
$('.slider:not(.swiper-slide-visible)').foggy();
```

Comment: thanks... so my JS would be like this:

$(document).ready( function(){
        $('.slider').foggy();
        $('.slider:not(..swiper-slide-visible)').foggy();
      });

Comment: No. It would be just  $(document).ready( function(){    $('.slider:not(.swiper-slide-visible)').foggy();  });

Comment: If this is working for you please accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Vinita - check here: http://orchards-dev.t3.ext.starberry.com/property-for-sale/house-for-sale/king-edwards-gardens-acton/104 it still put's the blur onto the main image that is .swiper-slide-visible

Comment: This is because ".slide.swiper-slide-visible.swiper-slide-active" these classes are not there when "$('.slider:not(.swiper-slide-visible)').foggy();" is fired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64300/discussion-between-vinita-rathore-and-user3544484).